# Trouble understanding how to implement Google Sheets API

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, google-sheets-api

I'm still learning web dev, hence my amateurish lingo, but I really need to be able to pull some data from a Google sheet and represent it visually in a Javascript-animated canvas object.

Unfortunately, as usual, the Google Sheets API documentation is not written with people like me in mind! The basic GETer application worked perfectly on my local Python server but now throws up an error since I tested it on a hosted website. I assume this is a JSONP issue since the error starts with 'Load denied by X-Frame-Options', but there doesn't seem to be any mention in the documentation of how to make the request as JSONP. I've made the spreadsheet public so there should be no need for an authentication step.

Here's the code, with IDs etc removed:

```
 <script>         

      var CLIENT_ID = 'my_client_id';

      var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"];

            function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
            'immediate': true
          }, handleAuthResult);
      }

 /**
       * Handle response from authorization server.
       *
       * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
       */
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {

        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          // Hide auth UI, then load client library.

          loadSheetsApi();
        } else {
          // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
          // clicking authorize button.
    console.log('nope');
        }
      }

      /**

      /**
       * Load Sheets API client library.
       */
      function loadSheetsApi() {
        var discoveryUrl =
            'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4';
        gapi.client.load(discoveryUrl).then(trackDonations);
      }

      /**
       * Print values in the donations column
       */
      function trackDonations() {
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: 'my_sheet_id',
          range: 'Form Responses 1!C2:C',
        }).then(function(response) {
          var range = response.result;
          if (range.values.length > 0) {
              console.log(range.values);
            $('.sum').text(range.values[range.values.length-1]);
          } else {
            prompt('No data found.');
          }
        }, function(response) {
          prompt('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
        });
      }



    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
```

Perhaps I'm missing something stupid, but would be very grateful for some guidance! Thanks!

Comment: To understand the Google Sheet API, kindly read - [Introducing the Google Sheets API v4](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/introducing-google-sheets-api-v4.html). This will provide basic and key information on Google Sheet v4. In this blog, they provide a Youtube [video](https://youtu.be/VLdrgE8iJZI?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq) - a sneak peak on using the API. They also provided a [codelab](https://g.co/codelabs/sheets) that explains a step by step implementation to become familiar with the Sheets API.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Rebot, I did read the documentation thoroughly, I just can't figure out how to get the authentication to work successfully on a website which is not hosted locally.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with a spreadsheet, it might be easier to use AppsScript.

From the spreadsheet, go to Tools > Script Editor. This page shows how to load the data into an array https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getDataRange() and then serve it as jsonp https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages If you then 'Deploy as web app' (the cloud icon), they will give you a url to reference in your code.

It's similar to using the rest api, but gives you more control over how the response works.

Comment: Thanks so much Mike, though the URL to the serving JSONP process seems to not exist...

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages